# Javascript / JQuery - redirect on window resize if at certain size

Tags: javascript, redirect, jquery

I'm trying to write some script which will redirect when the user resizes the screen to meet a certain threshold.

I'm using the JQuery window resize function and the code I've written is as follows:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ((window.width > 225px) && (window.width < 255px) && (window.height > 330px) && (window.height < 400px))
    {
    window.location = "URL GOES HERE"
    };
```

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea to me. I can easily imagine users getting suspicious when the browser suddenly starts reloading the page out of the blue. What is the exact problem you are trying to solve here? It's quite likely that it can be solved more elegantly (and less obtrusively) using CSS media queries (and maybe a little help from JS, but not redirecting or reloading).

Answer (score 7):

These are jQuery functions, so you have to wrap `window` in a jQuery object and call the functions on that: `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()`. Also, you don't need the `px`, because these functions [return only a number](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (($(window).width() > 225) && ($(window).width() < 255) && ($(window).height() > 330) && ($(window).height() < 400))
    {
        window.location = "URL GOES HERE"
    };
});
```

You could save them in a variable so you don't need to query them twice.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();
    if ((w > 225) && (w < 255) && (h > 330) && (h < 400)) {
        window.location = "URL GOES HERE";
    }
});
```

As [@tdammers suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374855/javascript-jquery-redirect-on-window-resize-if-at-certain-size/10374883#comment13373387_10374855) in a comment under your question, there must be a better solution to your problem than this.

Comment: is `225px` a valid keyword in javascript... ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've found a different and simpler / cleaner way of achieving what I wanted now using just HTML & CSS as suggested, but the answer has helped me understand where I was going wrong.

Comment: @JackWild Happy you found your solution! If you think my post answered your question, please accept it with the tickmark on the left of the answer.